# Manipulate Excel sheets programmatically

Tags: java, spreadsheet

I want to put some data into a Excel spreadsheet, and I have found some possibilities like Apache POI and JExcelApi, but the problem is, that I would like to keep the macros and formatting from the original spreadsheet.

Is that possible?

Comment: This has little to do with Android and almost everything to do with Java and the available spreadsheet JARs.